# How do I use Pow as my default server in Capybara?

Tags: capybara, rack-pow

I am enjoying using pow as my rack server during development and I would like to know if there is a simpler way to having it as my default server during capybara tests.
I have seen some people using:

`Capybara.run_server = false`

and setting pow to auto reload during each request by creating a file:

`tmp/always_restart.txt`

inside the project's home.